# Elegant way to add or subtract a fixed value depending on input

Tags: c#, math

Bear with me for a minute.

I have a method that should add or subtract a fixed value, depending on a given input.

I know that my max value is `1.0f`, the min value is `0.0f`. The fixed value is `0.1f`.

Now if the input value is `1.0f` the method should subtract until the value is `0f`. If the input value is `0f` the method should add `0.1f` until the value is `1.0f`.

So a working method for `0f` to `1f` would be:

```
void Foo(float input) {
    float step = .1f;
    for (float i=0f; i<=1f; i += step) {
        input = i;
    }
}
```

Obviously I could have an if-statement checking the input value, but is there another way to achieve this within one method? I feel like I'm just missing a very basic arithmetical operation here.

Comment: So you want to define a range for the `input` parameter to make sure it's between `0f` and `1f`?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something in particular (e.g, lerp from a to b in Unity), or is this a purely academic exercise?  (An interesting question, btw)

Comment: Do you want elegant, or do you want efficient? ;)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel You hit the nail. It is in fact for a `lerp` in Unity.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I don't need it to be efficient, only elegant :-)

Comment: @Soift, if that is the case I really, really, really think you should use the actual lerp or slerp library. There is funky stuff that goes down with GPUs and if statements (including ternary statements) and ultimately the unity libraries are by the laws of economics almost definitely more efficient than anything you would get in these answers. (I found the question interesting regardless, though :D )

Comment: @MaxvonHippel You're right. I am actually using `lerp` now, but I still like the approach of the accepted answer, although it still uses a conditional statement, but I guess there is not magic math there :-)

Comment: @Soift I like it too, as code.  Nonetheless, if you don't already know about it, I'd recommend you research 1) quaternions, and 2) when if statements are a problem and when they aren't - see form conversation [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177762-Performance-alternative-for-if-(-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just a suggestion

I think *step* could be adjusted to be positive or negative based on the initial value, and use a do-while so it runs the first time, until it hits the final value.

Based on your code

```
void Foo(float input) {
    float step = input == 0f ? .1f : -0.1f;

    do 
    {
        input = input + step
    } while (input > 0f && input < 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really avoid using an if statement at all for the step, you can actually derive it from the input directly. In turn you might get some extra numerical errors, but as you're using floats already this might not be of your concern.

```
void foo(float input)
{
    float step = (.5f - input)/5.f;
    do 
    {
        input += step;
    } while (input > 0.0f && input < 1.0f);
}
```

Running it on my machine gives me

```
foo(1.0f) --> -7.45058e-08
foo(0.0f) --> 1
```

Comment: Oh nice! This was the kind of 'hack' I was actually looking for. So `.5f` is just the mean score of my `min` and `max` value?

Comment: @Soift In this case, yes. If you want to have a variable `max` and `min` I'm not sure if it will be that simple (especially if you still want a constant step size)